# Set up an extended form (django-userena)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Say I have started a Django app called `accounts`, I want the model to extend the [UserenaBaseProfile](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/models.py) class. So far I have done that with this code from the django-userena tutorial.

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),
                                       max_length=5)
```

I am still unsure on how to use a form to create a user with fields more than what are included in `userena/models.py`. That models file contains the `UserenaBaseProfile` that I inherit from in `accounts/models.py` in the MyProfile class. The field `favorite_snack` is an just some arbitrary field I want to extend with (as done in the django-userena tutorial).

From there, if what is done so far is even done correctly, my real question is how do I extend the default `userena/forms.py` form (This is for account creation, so I am wanting to extend the class `SignupForms` since [*it](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/forms.py) only contains fields for `username`,  `password,` and `email`. Of course I am looking to extend the signup form with  a `favorite_snack` form field, since this is a field I extended to my user class.

Sorry if I am missing something big, I am new to Django and web development! I  tried to leave the code examples as similar to the [django-userena docs](http://www.django-userena.org/) as possible in attempt to help others starting out with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `F.A.Q` session of userena's doc there is: [How do I add extra fields to forms?](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-add-extra-fields-to-forms)

This is exactly what you're looking for. They include there the `First name` and `Last name` in a new form that overrides userena's default. See at the end that it needs to be done some tweaks to the `urls.py`

In your case, you need to save the `favourite_snack` in the `save` method of your new form, the same way they do with `First name` and `Last name`

Hope this helps!